# 2008R2 mstsc RDP log in via system service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I have a windows service which monitors the local RDP server and ensures that certain local users' sessions are logged on and active.

It does this by waiting on WTSWaitSystemEvent and checking the list of RDP sessions when events happen, and generating a .rdp file which is then launched by mstsc (`mstsc [tmprdpfile].rdp`).

The service runs as SYSTEM.

This works perfectly on Server 2003 R2, and appears to nearly work (:)) on 2008 R2. The .rdp files are generated correctly -- when run manually they log in with no password prompt -- and `mstsc` is launched correctly, but the sessions never connect. This results in an ever-increasing number of `mstsc` processes being launched.

Is it possible to:

1. Inspect a running `mstsc` instance to see what it's doing? I suspect a password prompt or server authentication warning (though `authentication level:i:0` is set).
2. Somehow get a screen print of a gui application which is running under a system service (I know, this is a weird situation to be in in the first place)?

(If anyone has suggestions on a better method to meet my requirements (multiple user sessions must be kept logged in *and active* automatically) I'm open to that too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with was running the service as local user.

This meant I could log in to that user's desktop and manually run `mstsc`, where sure enough, an "are you sure" prompt appeared.

Once I ticked the "don't ask me again for connections to this computer" box, running my service under this user account worked correctly

It may also be possible to add the correct entry to SYSTEM's `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server\Client\LocalDevices\` to avoid creating a new account, but to me the unprivileged account seems better in general.